# Which compiler is right? Structured binding SFINAE

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++20

I made the following code sample to understand if a particular structure has exactly 3 members, using lambda in unevaluated context. It seems that clang works as expected whereas GCC does not count the error as a SFINAE error, and msvc just always fails to determine the right answer.

```cpp
template <typename Type>
constexpr bool has_3_members()
{
    if constexpr (requires { [](Type && type){ auto && [x1, x2, x3] = type; }; }) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the full code: https://godbolt.org/z/39zKaMnh1

Anyone can explain which compiler is right and whether this is supposed to work under the C++20 standard?

Also appreciate if you have alternative ways that work with the above code.

Comment: Please post all the code into the actual question. And no, you cannot SFINAE on structured bindings - you can SFINAE only on expressions and structured bindings are declarations.

Comment: If you take a look in the code the declaration is placed in a lambda expression so what makes that illegal in the standard? Also it works in clang-13 so it gives some hope that it is legal @Barry

Comment: Maybe related: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71879 ?

Comment: @Klaus I didn't see how it is related but I was using gcc 11.2 and they said it was fixed in 11.

Comment: It says that there is a problem with unevaluated context which breaks in same cases. As lambdas are new in c++20 for unevaluated context, it might be an unfixed part...

Comment: @Klaus I am mostly trying to understand if this is legal C++20 or there is some issue with the error not being in the immediate context or something that would prevent this from being legal C++20

Comment: The link to the duplicate says it is not valid.

Comment: The link is talking about templates type deduction however I could not find a clause in the standard for requires expression @Klaus